# Troubleshooting hotstring expansion in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am experiencing inconsistent hotstring expansions in ahk. For example the following hotstring

```
:o:192.::192.168.
```

worked till yesterday, but after today's boot/reboot cycle , it isn't.

The hotkeys still work, like this one below

```
OpenClipboardFileWith(app)
{
    ;Run, Notepad.exe
    fname = %Clipboard% ;Open file in Clipboard, if it exists - similar to functionality in DOPUS
    ;MsgBox Before %fname%
    StringSplit, fname, fname, `r`n
    ;MsgBox %fname0%
    if (fname0 > 0) {
        ;convert newline seperated files to space seperated arguments for program
        StringReplace, fname, fname, `r`n, "%A_Space%", All
        fname = "%fname%"
        ;MsgBox parameters are %fname%
    }
    If !FileExist(fname1) {
        ;check for single element first
        fname = 
    }
    Loop %fname0%-1
    {
        element := fname%A_Index%
        ;element = "%element%"
        ;MsgBox %element%
        ;params = %params% %element%
        If !FileExist(element) {
            ;MsgBox Resetting fname as %element% doesn't exist.
            fname = 
        }
    }
    ;MsgBox After %app% %fname%
    Run, %app% %fname%
  return
}
#y::OpenClipboardFileWith(Share "\Programs\@Text\Editors\Notepad2\notepad2.exe") ;;Notepad (open file on clipboard)
#n:: Run, notepad.exe
```

So I don't know what the issue is. This happens on and off and I had experienced this problem on another computer as well. I am guessing it has to do with the keyboard and mouse hooks. I checked in the script listing (right click ahk icon > vew script info) and it was fine, the hooks are installed.

How do I go about resolving this issue?

I tested if it running as admin.

```
MsgBox , , , %A_IsAdmin%
```

and it says 1. I event tried these programs http://www.tranglos.com/activehotkeys/ and http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/index.html but no help from those. It shows me the regular hotkeys as being registered, but nothing about hotstrings. Any other tools that can detect and sort these issues out? The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465135/detecting-keyboard-hooks is of no help.

Anybody else seeing similar issues?

Another related issue might be that, drag & drop randomly stops working, and I have to use the press and hold left mouse button, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> several times to get it to work (not consistently though).

I am guessing that out of the various programs installed on the pc, one is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with "drag & drop" is a lesser known Windows 7 "feature". The way to restore drag & drop until Redmond has found the time to patch it, is to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> and then when the blue selection page pops up, hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> again. I know it sounds stupid, but it works every time.

For one reason or the other your:

```
:o:192.::192.168.
```

still required a space, so I changed it to:

```
:*:192.::192.168.
```

Which works flawlessly.

Comment: thanks for the tip on the Esc button. But I still have problem with expansion. I don't mind the space requirement. Another example that won't work is `:c?:@sig::Regards,{Enter 2}Name ;;`

Comment: For one reason or the other your expansion initially did not work here either. Once I removed the c? and @ it worked and after I placed the c? and @ back it continued working. I suggest to throw it away and type (not copy) it again. Not sure why. B.t.w. why did you add the ?, This means that it will expand if you write a letter to ABC@signals.com to ABCRegards,Namenals.com...

Comment: good point. Didn't think of it in the email context i suppose. Ok I'll try. Tested `::test::Woohoo` it didn't work. in a new blank script. Using AHK 1.1.9.2

Comment: This is strange. I use 1.1.09.01. Does autoHotKey keep running (Green H icon) or does it close immediately after you started it?

Comment: B.t.w. Most text expansions that I do end with \ this way they are unique. Example :*:cp\::c-Projects{Space} so cp\ is converted to c-Projects

Comment: Since you seem to have weird behaviour, have you tried re-installing AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 0):

It finally started working after disabling UAC.

Comment: Ugh I had this problem on another computer again. Disabled UAC and it's working, but I still don't know why it happened in the first place when it was working with UAC for a while. I think maybe an update disabled this? Anybody with more insight into the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem with some of my expansions not working. But the problem was the script itself.
I included a script which someone else had written however I didn't realise quite the way it worked.

It had a directive like

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Blah
```

It didn't have an ending blank

```
#IfWinActive
```

What that meant was that all the hotkeys and expansions following that initial directive (which was most of my expansions) were only applied in the context **Blah**

To fix it I added the extra directive

```
#IfWinActive
```

after the one which started it. That makes the context apply to anything again.

An example of a problem script would be

```
;This is for in a Console Window
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
#a::
; Some short cut here
    return

::ex::Some expand which I expect to happen in all situations (which doesn't)
```

To fix that script you would need to do the following

```
;This is for in a Console Window
#IfWinActive, ahk_class ConsoleWindowClass
#a::
; Some short cut here
    return
#IfWinActive

::ex::Some expand which I expect to happen in all situations (which  it now does)
```

For more information on how this works look at
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm